# how to build reactive api with spring Webflux and dynamodb?

Tags: spring, amazon-dynamodb, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I read new java aws sdk for dynamodb supports non-blocking I/O.

i am trying out spring webflux app by creating repository by extending ReactiveCrudRepository.

Do I need to write all low level api implementations(for all CRUD operations with Flux and Mono) or no need ?

Can suggest how to go about this?

Comment: read the official documentation